# Special For Xml in SqlServer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, for-xml

we have a simple table and need convert to XML

```
 Declare @Person TABLE
(   [BusinessEntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PersonType] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](30) NULL)

Insert Into @Person Values(10001,'IN','Article','Carolyn','Jo','Alonso')
```

we need this xml for output with For XML in sql server

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='result.xsl'?>
<documents>
  <document>
    <field name="BusinessEntityID">10001</field>
    <field name="PersonType">IN</field>
    <field name="Title">Article</field>
    <field name="FirstName">Carolyn</field>
    <field name="MiddleName">Jo</field>
    <field name="LastName">Alonso</field>
  </document>
 </documents>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following XML PATH query should get you most of the way. You just need to add the stylesheet header.

```
SELECT 
'BusinessEntityID' AS 'document/field/@name'
,   BusinessEntityID AS 'document/field'
,   '' AS 'document'
,   'documentType' AS 'document/field/@name'
,   PersonType AS 'document/field'
,   '' AS 'document'
,   'Title' AS 'document/field/@name'
,   Title AS 'document/field'
,   '' AS 'document'
,   'FirstName' AS 'document/field/@name'
,   FirstName AS 'document/field'
,   '' AS 'document'
,   'MiddleName' AS 'document/field/@name'
,   MiddleName AS 'document/field'
,   '' AS 'document'
,   'LastName' AS 'document/field/@name'
,   LastName AS 'document/field'
,   '' AS 'document'
FROM @Person
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('documents')
```